# How to bounce an email back to the sender in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

There is a moron (not spammer) that keeps sending me unwanted emails. Currently those emails are directed to the junk folder in Outlook, but I want a different solution. I want to bounce the emails back to the sender, essentially telling the person the emails cannot be delivered to my address, or perhaps my address is no longer valid. Any solution in Outlook? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Bouncing back one mail might not be a good idea.

If the attacker is spoofing some one else address you will end up bouncing the emails to the spoofed address.

Other possible issue is that replies will generate traffic that might be bouncing back and forward between servers causing problems.

The most efficient way is to include his address in some anti-spam list if your company has one so the server blocks connections / drop emails from the originators. Or enable anti-spam techniques that might be diverse depending on the engine you use. 
Some send one email back to the originator asking for the originator to confirm he exists and is human by doing some actions... (most annoying ones...) if nothing is done the email is discarded...

If not a corporation email and you are using outlook.com / hotmail or gmail.com check in their web-mail site if there is spam classification / button, insert the emails that you are receiving as spam.

If other users are also complaining their algorithm will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware if there's any setting within MS Outlook to bounce a mail, so strictly speaking this post does not truly answer your question. However I personally use a third party app called MailWasher on Windows 7 that is capable of bouncing mails from within the app, before reaching your actual Mail Client.

Run Mailwasher and configure your POP3 account, also configure Bouncing settings with correct SMTP details. Now preview mails thru Mailwasher and select which one you wish to delete/bounce off the mail server and process the same.

Once done, now download the rest (actual interested ones) in to your Mail Client.

You have not mentioned if you are on home internet or in some corporate network. Any policy settings in corporate network might prevent installation and bouncing of mails thru third party apps though.